# paypal sandbox not receiving $_POST["txn_id"]

Tags: paypal, transactions, sandbox

I am using a **PayPal SandBox** for testing purposes. All was working fine, but all of a sudden I stopped receiving the `txn_id`. I am using

```
$_POST["txn_id"]
```

to check whether it is a request or a response. Help Please.

I just realized that it is not about $_POST["tex_id"], the "notify_url" is not working in the PayPal response. It was working up till yesterday, not sure what went wrong. Any Suggestions?